# is there a way to ensure that drivers have been updated properly?

Tags: drivers, updates, cpu-usage

recently, I have updated some drivers in windows 8.1,but I have noticed some weird changes.for instance,my CPU and GPU temperature have never exceeded 70C while gaming,but they do now even the temps increase to 78C.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are loaded by the System process. One way to gain visibility as to which drivers are currently loaded, the versions and where they are loaded from is to run [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from Microsoft/Sysinternals.

There are a number of built-in utilities such as driverquery.exe, msinfo32.exe which can be used but the presentation of the information with Process Explorer is very good as shown below:

[image: Process Explorer]

Note: There are a number of additional columns that can be added to the lower pain, I've added the ones I believe are the most helpful.

You will typically find that best practice for developers is to store their drivers under %windir%\system32\drivers.  Not all of the sys files under this location are typically loaded so you can use Process Explorer to show which ones are currently running.

The time the driver was signed is probably the best reflection of when it was built and therefore how new it is. If you know what version of the driver you're expecting to be loaded you can check that also.

As some drivers can't be updated without a system restart, I would suggest restarting the computer to give the relevant installer the chance to complete its upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to both check and update drivers is to go to Device Manager. Expand each section on the first screen and check (1) that there are no red or yellow exclamation marks and (2) right click, Update Driver and see if there are updates to do. Do this for your main drivers: Video (Display), Network (all cards), Bluetooth, Sound (Audio), Power Driver, and any that need updating (yellow marks).  This works very well.

If you have a Driver Update Application from your PC Manufacturer, you can also run this to update drivers and then check Device Manager that all is done.